# Nuxt: Can't access vuex store from js file

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I'm creating an app with Vuex state management in Nuxt. The problem is I want to create js file with functions, which I will import into my Vue files. I need to access my store in that file.

In functions.js I want to import store using `import store from "@/store"`, but `store` gives me empty object. When I do `import store from "@/store/dice.js"`, which is store I want to access It return undefined and in a console I got information: `"export 'default' (imported as '$store') was not found in '~/store/dice'`

`@/store/index.js` is empty.

`@/store/dice.js` got structure like in Nuxt tutorial:

```js
export const state = () => ({
    list: []
})
export const mutations = {
    add(state, text) {
        state.list.push({
            text,
            done: false
        })
    },
    remove(state, {
        todo
    }) {
        state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
    },
    toggle(state, todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex Store files located in `store` directory will be transformed by Nuxt to become a store instance when build time.

So you can't import any files from them into other `js` files outside the store.

You have to solutions:

1. **Which is recommended:** Add your `function.js` folder into your store and use your functions there (call them inside mutations, actions, etc...)
2. **Which is NOT recommended:** When calling your functions in `function.js` pass your store instance as a parameter, then you can use it.